# How do I remove a system CSS file in a theme?

Tags: theming, 8

I am trying to remove Drupal CSS files (such as ajax-progress.module.css) from my custom theme YML. Here is what I tried:

```
name: Mercante
type: theme
description: Tema para o site Mercante.co
core: 8.x
stylesheets-remove:
  - core/themes/stable/css/system/components/ajax-progress.module.css
libraries-override:
  system/base:
    css:
      theme:
        css/components/ajax-progress.module.css: false
```

Drupal's documentation about that is scarce at best...

Update: another version that also does not work:

```
name: Mercante
type: theme
description: Tema para o site Mercante.co
core: 8.x
stylesheets-remove:
  - @stable/css/system/components/ajax-progress.module.css
libraries-override:
  system/base:
    css:
      component:
        /core/themes/stable/css/system/components/ajax-progress.module.css: false
        /core/themes/stable/css/system/components/autocomplete-loading.module.css: false
```

Comment: Reference link: https://www.drupal.org/node/2642122

Answer (score 3):

You can try with the unset method that drupal provides for [css alter hook](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_css_alter/7). Try the following code in your custom module

```
function hook_css_alter(&$css) { 
unset($css[drupal_get_path('module','system').'/system.theme.css']);}
```

Comment: But I guess the "correct" way to remove a CSS is through libraries-override isn't it? Even stylesheets-remove didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct. This is what I have and it is working:

```
libraries-override:
  core/normalize:
    css:
      base:
        assets/vendor/normalize-css/normalize.css: false
```

Comment: Do you think there is any difference since I am removing something from system/base?

Comment: I think you have wrong paths. You have to use the paths defined in the library and not absolute paths.

Answer (score 1):

Quote from https://www.drupal.org/node/2473869

> ```
> stylesheets-remove:
>   - core/assets/vendor/jquery.ui/themes/base/dialog.css
> ```
>
> In cases where a Drupal core asset is being removed (for example, a
>   CSS file in jQuery UI) the full file path is needed. In cases where
>   the file is part of a library that belongs to a module or theme, a
>   token can be used. Note that when using the token it needs to be
>   quoted because @ is a reserved indicator in YAML.
>
> ```
> stylesheets-remove:
>   - '@bartik/css/style.css'
> ```

As you are removing a stylesheet from the stable theme you should use the token `@stable`

Comment: I tried that, also not working.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I managed to do it:

```
name: Mercante
type: theme
description: Tema para o site Mercante.co
core: 8.x
base theme: false
libraries-override:
  system/base:
    css:
      component:
        /core/modules/system/css/components/align.module.css: false
```